What is minimum of the integral function $I(x)= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+t^x)^x} \,dt$
A while ago I stumbled on a YT movie with regards the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+x^\phi)^\phi} dx = 1 .$$ Here $\phi=1.6180\ldots$ is the Golden Ratio.
But then I thought, what will happen if you take $\phi$ as the variable and increase or decrease its value? You'll get the following function: $$I(x) =\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+t^x)^x}dt .$$
with $I(\phi) = 1$.
So making $x$ smaller I noticed at $1$ there is a pole which goes to $+\infty$.
But much nicer is letting $x$ get much larger. What I did not expect is that if $x$ gets very large the value of $I(x)$ seems to go "back" to 1 again.
I can not check that further than $708$ because after (at $709$) Wolfram times out and gives an error.
But this means that there's a minimum between phi and infinity.
I found that minimum (using public wolfram) to be around $x = 3.542$.
BUT, all values between $3.539$ and $3.546$ give the same lowest answer and that is $0,66568$
And then at $3.538$ or $3.547$ Wolfram gives $0,665681$.
So the question is: What is the exact minimum value and at what $x$ is that? And how can that be derived?

It is an interesting problem. Can you please show your link to Wolfram?

there is no variable to integrate wrt, dx missing?

Notice that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+t^x)^x}dt = \frac{\Gamma(x-1/x)\Gamma(1+1/x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$

using the above explicit expression, you need to solve $\psi^{(0)}(1+1/x) + x^2 \psi^{(0)}(x) - (1+x^2)\psi^{(0)}(x-1/x) = 0$. where $\psi^{(0)}$ is the digamma function.

I must have accidentally deleted the 2nd comment by Yimin with a link to Wolfram and answer is  x ≈ 3.5427402855522466975019190 , so here is link again:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+%28polygamma%280%2C+1+%2B+1%2Fx%29+%2B+x%5E2+polygamma%280%2C+x%29+-+%281+%2B+x%5E2%29+polygamma%280%2C+-1%2Fx+%2B+x%29%29+%3D+0%2C+x>3

A nice approximation :(thanks to the ISC) is $$\frac{\log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\Gamma
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$ which is in absolute error of $5.6\times 10^{-8}$

Substituting $u = (1 + t^x)^{-1}$ transforms the integral to
$$I(x) = \frac1x \int_0^1 u^{x - \frac1x - 1} (1 - u)^{\frac1x - 1} \,du
= \frac1x \mathrm{B}\left(x - \frac1x, \frac1x\right)
= \frac{\Gamma\left(x - \frac1x\right) \Gamma\left(\frac1x\right)}{x \Gamma(x)} ,$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ denotes the beta function. Applying an identity of the gamma function shows that this formula agrees with the one given by @TheSilverDoe in the comments.
To look for a critical point of $I$, we search for zeroes of the derivative. Differentiating, applying gamma function identities, and factoring yields
$$I'(x) = \frac{\Gamma\left(x - \frac1x\right) \Gamma\left(\frac1x\right) \left[(1 + x^2) \psi\left(x - \frac1x\right) - x^2 \psi(x) - x - \psi\left(\frac1x\right)\right]}{x^2 \Gamma(x + 1)} .$$
Since $\Gamma$ has no zeroes, the critical points of $I$ are the zeroes of
$$g(x) := (1 + x^2) \psi\left(x - \frac1x\right) - x^2 \psi(x) - x - \psi\left(\frac1x\right) ,$$
where $\psi$ is the digamma function, $\psi(x) := \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$.
The function $g$ is decreasing on the set $(1, \infty)$ on which $I(x)$ converges, and we have that
$$g(3) = -\frac92 - \frac{11 \pi}{2 \sqrt 3} + \frac{27 \log 3}{2} > 0 > -\frac{1208}{231} - 9 \pi + 48 \log 2 = g(4) ,$$ so $I$ has a unique critical point $x_0 \in (3, 4)$. The global minimum $I(x_0)$ of $I$ is bounded above by the closed-form expression $I(4) = \frac{77 \pi}{256 \sqrt 2} = 0.66816\ldots $. I doubt that $x_0$ or $I(x_0)$ is expressible explicitly in terms of standard functions.
Computing numerically gives that the critical point is
$$x_0 = 3.54274\,02855\,52246\,69750 \ldots ,$$
and the minimum of $I$ is
$$I(x_0) = 0.66568\,02462\,43430\,33442 \ldots ,$$
in agreement with the values in the question statement. Neither of these values match entries in the Inverse Symbolic Calculator. We can see, incidentally, that our upper bound $I(4) = \frac{77 \pi}{256 \sqrt 2}$ is reasonably good, less than $0.4\%$ larger than the actual minimum.
Remark By the way, you're right that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} I(x) = 1$. More precisely, the asymptotics of the gamma function give the asymptotic
$$I(x) = 1 - \frac{\log x + \gamma}{x} + R_1(x), \qquad R_1(x) \in O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right)$$
as $x \to \infty$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
Similarly, as $x \searrow 1$, we have
$$I(x) = \frac12 (x - 1)^{-1} - \frac14 + R_2(x), \qquad R_2(x) \in O(x - 1) .$$

Interesting problem for sure. Nice to meet you again on the site.

@ClaudeLeibovici Likewise, cheers!

@TravisWillse Congratulations for the 100K :) Great answer as always

@Gwen Thank you!

Congratulations !!

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you!

$$I(x)= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+t^x)^x} \,dt=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \Gamma \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\Gamma(x)}$$ Take logarithms and differentiate
$$\frac{I'(x)}{I(x)}=-\frac{x^2 \psi (x)-\left(x^2+1\right) \psi
 \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\psi \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}$$
Using one single iteration of Householder method with $x_0=\frac 72$ gives a (long) explicit result. Converted to decimals
$$x_{\text{min}}=\color{red}{3.5427402}74\qquad \text{and} \qquad =\color{red}{0.66568024624343033}64$$
$I(x_{\text{min}})$ is much accurate than $x_{\text{min}}$ because $I''(x_{\text{min}})\sim 0.0321$ (very flat curve around the minimum).
Playing with the order $n$ of the method, converting the explicit result to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &  x_{\text{min}}^{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  3.542290681774577 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 &  3.542741558768349 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 &  3.542740274073643 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  3.542740285682765 & \text{no name}\\
 6 &  3.542740285550602 & \text {no name}\\     
\cdots & \cdots \\  
\infty &  3.542740285552245& \text {solution}\\         
\end{array}
\right)$$
If $x$ tends to $1^+$
$$I(x)=\frac{1}{2 (x-1)}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3+4 \pi ^2}{24}
   (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
If $x$ tends to $\infty$
$$I(x)=1-\frac{\log (x)+\gamma }{x}+\frac{6 \log ^2(x)+12 \gamma  \log (x)+\pi ^2+6
   \gamma ^2+6}{12 x^2}+O\left(\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3}\right)$$
